# Compile/Configure Options of a Yum Package (RPM)

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, bind, yum

Is it possible to get the compile options of a yum package? In this particular case, I am trying to get them for the standard BIND installation with CentOS, but if there is a generic way for YUM packages that would be good to know as well.

So to be clear this would be all the options passed during the build process of the bind binaries in the yum package during the compile process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generic way is to download the source RPM and look in the `.spec` file. Install the `yum-utils` package, and run `yumdownloader --source bind`, and then unpack the downloaded source RPM (with either `rpm -ivh` or `rpm2cpio`) and look.

Many programs also have an application-specific way of getting compile options. Unfortunately (see comments) the RHEL 5 / CentOS 5 version of BIND does not have any such option, so you're pretty much reduced to looking at the build options in the spec file. Newer versions of BIND, however, do provide a way: run `/usr/sbin/named -V` for version number and build options. (Many programs happen to follow this `-V` convention, `perl` and Apache `httpd` among them. But it's by no means standard.)

Comment: -V was the first thing I ran, for some reason the stock named in CentOS says it is an invalid option. (also tried `-v` which only shows the version number and `--version` which is another unknown)

Comment: Whoops -- you're right. From the changelog, that added in 9.6.0a1, and RHEL/CentOS 5 have version 9.3.x. I'll edit my answer. Yet another reason for RHEL 6. :)